# Website Banner Background Color

Tags: html, iphone, css, colors

I have made a website: [www.co-ceramics.co.uk](http://www.co-ceramics.co.uk)

Quite simple but it's what the client wants. However, if I view this on my iphone. The blue background color of the banner doesnt display correctly (all the way to the right).

Maybe I have to set up a certain style sheet for the iphone's resolution?

Or is there something much more simpler than this?

Thanks!
Ian

Comment: I think #banner {width:100%} is causing this, setting up a separate @media for the iPhone screen would fix it.

Comment: Use media queries - basic principles: no floats, 'row' structure -> (every content 'block' bellow each other, etc, etc...). Firefox web developer plugin have nice feature - responsive design view - it is very helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using this:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
```

The width is doing exactly what it should be, its getting the screen size and displaying 100%, however your elements inside the banner go past the width which is why its pushing things out.

Comment: Thanks! Never have really noticed how that code effects the webpage!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to check if mobile / Iphone or not (JS Code).

```
if (screen.width <= 699) {
  // Check if mobile
 }



if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    // Check if Iphone
}
```

Now when you can find out if user use mobile you can make lite version to your css code or change width and height to same as mobile that your background will work.

Other way is to percents instead of pixels (width: 600px <- Match only few screens, width: 100% <- Match all screens all over the screen).

Hope i helped

EDIT:

Just to make clear the screen width part, you can replace your stylesheet by using `document.write` or `innerHTML` and create new css file with improved code.